# google app engine access version number

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to access the version number specified in my XML config file from my java code.
How could I do this?

The goal is to make sure that users will have access to the latest version of my JavaScript by appending it to it file.js?x=version-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the version # you are refering to is your application version number and not the current App Engine Version.

If that is the case, you could look at the following approaches:

- Ship a version.txt file with your web application that is updated with every new version that you push to App Engine.
- Have a Version.java, where you keep the current version
- There could be an initialization Servlet that could have an initParam that refers to the current version #.

Each of these have their +/- points - but you could pick an approach.